# Is there any impact of OpenJDK 8 (Zulu 1.8.0_282) on libraries like Spring 3, Hibernate 3, XStream etc?

Tags: java, java-8, azul-zulu

Our project is a legacy project running on Java 7 and we plan to migrate from Oracle Java 7 to OpenJDK 8 (Zulu).
We use following 3rd party libraries and I wanted to know if migrating to Zulu's OpenJDK 8 will have any impact on using these 3rd party libraries.

**OpenJDK version**: -

> ```
> openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.52.0.23-CA-win64) (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.52.0.23-CA-win64) (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
> ```

**Libraries used by the project**: -

> ```
> hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
> hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.patched.jar
> hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
> h2-1.3.173.jar
> spring-aop-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> spring-asm-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> spring-aspects-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> spring-context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> spring-context-support-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> spring-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> spring-expression-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> spring-test-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> spring-tx-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar
> xstream-1.4.7.jar
> ```

Please let me know if there is any link or blog where the compatibility is mentioned or if there is any impact on these libraries and we will need to upgrade the mentioned libraries too ?

Comment: Is there a reason why they should not?

Comment: In theory it could work, however those libraries aren't certified nor tested on JDK8 (Spring 3.2.x is the first one that is compatible with JDK8).

Comment: @Abra various reasons for selecting Zulu ... our production env is Windows based, it was certified by our IT team, LTS etc

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to state categorically that there will be no impact in making this change of runtime.  In addition to the changes between JDK 7 and JDK 8 (which there were many), there have been numerous included in all the updates to JDK 8.  Testing your application is the only way to know.

Zulu is a build of OpenJDK and TCK tested so functionally identical to any other build of OpenJDK that is TCK tested.

One thing that might catch you out is specifically in the latest update to JDK 8, u292, which turned off support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 by default.  This caught me out on an application using MySQL and JDBC so your list of libraries might be affected as well.  If this does cause problems it is easy to turn the version of TLS back on in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file (look for the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` section).

Comment: Thank you @Speakjava... we will consider this... like Oracle has a matrix or table of compatibility between different versions of JDBC drivers and JDK ... i thought if only one such is available for Spring, hibernate and other such framework libraries and OpenJDK versions/vendors...thank you :)